# Prove $\tau=\inf\{t\in[0,T]:M_t=0\}\wedge T$ a stopping time for a continuous martingale $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

I have a question about a positive continuous martingale.
Let $(M_t)_{t\in[0,T]}$ be a continuous martingale such that $P(M_t>0)=1$ for all $t\in[0,T]$. Set $\tau=\inf\{t\in[0,T]:M_t=0\}\wedge T$.
I want to shaw what $\tau$ is a stopping time. It is clearly bounded, so if $\tau$ is indeed a stopping time, I can apply the optional sampling theorem.

Comment: Thanks to the positivity assumption, $\tau \equiv T$.

Comment: @zhoraster: It's not completely obvious, since $P(M_t > 0)=1$ for all $t$ is not the same as $P(M_t > 0 \text{ for all $t$}) = 1$.

Comment: @NateEldredge, yes, but since it is a martingale, we have $E[(M_T-M_\tau)|\mathcal F_\tau] = 0$, which means that $M_T = 0$ on $\{\tau<T\}$. So the latter has probability $0$. Or maybe wrong? No, seems ok.

Comment: @zhoraster: I think you're applying the optional stopping theorem to deduce that $E[M_\tau \mid \mathcal{F}_\tau] = E[M_T \mid \mathcal{F}_\tau]$, which requires that we first know that $\tau$ is a stopping time!

Comment: @NateEldredge, for us, $\tau$ a stopping time undoubtedly (but I let the OP show it). Anyway, my question is why one needs to introduce $\tau\equiv T$ in this bizarre way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. We are done if we can show that $$\{\tau \leq t\} = \{\omega; \inf_{r \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,t]} |M_r(\omega)|=0\} =: \Omega_t$$ for any $t \leq T$.
2. $\{\tau \leq t\} \subseteq \Omega_t$: Fix $\omega \in \{\tau \leq t\}$. Then, there exists $s \in [0,t]$ such that $M_s(\omega)=0$. Use the continuity of $s \mapsto M_s(\omega)$ to deduce that there exists a sequence $(s_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq [0,t] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ such that $s_j \to s$ and $M_{s_j}(\omega) \to M_s(\omega)=0$.
3. $\Omega_t \subseteq \{\tau \leq t\}$: This is equivalent to $$\Omega_t^c \supseteq \{\tau \leq t\}^c = \{\tau>t\}.$$ So let $\omega \in \Omega_t^c$, that is $$\inf_{r \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,t]} |M_r(\omega)|>0.$$ Decude from the continuity of the sample paths that $$\inf_{r \in [0,t]} |M_r(\omega)|>0.$$ Conclude that $\tau(\omega)>t$.

**Remark:** The proof boils down to the following, very fundamental, result:

> Let $f:[0,t] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function for some fixed $t>0$. Then the following statements are equivalent.
>
> 1. There exists $s \in [0,t]$ such that $f(s)=0$.
> 2. $\inf_{r \in [0,t] \cap \mathbb{Q}} |f(r)|=0$.

Exactly the same argumentation shows that $$\tau_F := \inf\{t \in [0,T]; M_t \in F\}$$ is a stopping time for any closed set $F$.